# Scala's sealed abstract vs abstract class

Tags: scala, class, abstract, sealed

What is the difference between `sealed abstract` and `abstract` Scala class?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The difference is that all subclasses of a sealed class (whether it's abstract or not) must be in the same file as the sealed class.

Comment: Something not so obvious (at least it was not for me :-)) is that "grand children" of the sealed class can be in other files too:
Given sealed class A; B extends A; C extends B. B must be in the same file as A, but C can leave in the same or in another.

Comment: @SandorMurakozi You must declare B as a sealed class as well, if you want to achieve that. Sealing only deals with direct inheritance.

Answer (score 80):

As [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032771/scalas-sealed-abstract/3032787#3032787), all *directly inheriting* subclasses of a sealed class (abstract or not) must be in the same file. A practical consequence of this is that the compiler can warn if the pattern match is incomplete. For instance:

```
sealed abstract class Tree
case class Node(left: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree
case class Leaf[T](value: T) extends Tree
case object Empty extends Tree

def dps(t: Tree): Unit = t match {
  case Node(left, right) => dps(left); dps(right)
  case Leaf(x) => println("Leaf "+x)
  // case Empty => println("Empty") // Compiler warns here
}
```

If the `Tree` is `sealed`, then the compiler warns unless that last line is uncommented.

Comment: Why can't the compiler infer that pattern match is incomplete if there is no `sealed` keyword?

Comment: @sasha.sochka Suppose I compile it and put it in a jar file, without the `sealed` keyword. It's all been compiled at that point, including the `match` statement. Now, another user grabs this jar and _extends `Tree`_. There's nothing preventing him from doing so, but, at that point, the `match` statement is no longer complete. Since he isn't compiling it, just using it from your jar, the compiler can't warn _him_. And since you did not know of it when you created the jar, it couldn't have warned you.

Comment: @DanielCSobral, You wrote "but, at *that* point, the match statement is no longer complete". Isn't the match statement incomplete at *this* moment, when you compile the original code you posted (but without `sealed` keyword), before making a jar file? It looks like easy to infer, because even without new children (compiler doesn't know about them yet) there is no branch for `Empty`. And I'm talking about a warning for the person who creates a jar, not about a person who uses it.

Comment: @sasha.sochka Well, I suppose it could warn that `Empty` is missing, but the point is that, even if you add `Empty`, it could still be incomplete, or not, depending on what happens at separate compilations.

Comment: Yes, then I agree with you.