# Scala generics: specializing a method

Tags: scala, generics

In Haskell I can define a generic type for a tree as:

```
type Tree t = Leaf t | Node (Tree t) (Tree t)
```

If I want to define a function for a specific parameterization of Tree, I can simply do:

```
-- Signature of a function that takes a tree of bool
foo :: Tree Bool -> Int

-- Takes a tree of numbers
bar :: (Num n) => Tree n -> Bool
```

We can define a similar tree type in Scala with:

```
abstract class Tree[T]()
case class Leaf[T](t: T) extends Tree[T]
case class Node[T](left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]
```

But how can I define a method for Tree that only applies to certain types? Do I need to use inheritance or there's a way to say:

```
abstract class Tree[T]() {
  // Method only for Tree[String]:
  def foo[String] = ...
}
```

Comment: What would happen to `foo` if the `Tree`'s type was `Int`? What do you expect? `val t: Tree[Int] = ...` and `t.foo()`?

Comment: I'd expect foo (like the Haskell example) to be only defined for Tree[Int]. This is why I wonder if I need to use inheritance to create a new class from tree, but it seems contrived to derive a new class just to define a specialized method.

Comment: Instead of adding a method to the `Tree` itself, you could create a function that takes the tree as a parameter. The function could declare a specific type of tree (e.g. `def foo(tree:Tree[String])`) or it could use the type class pattern, if you want to make it generic.

Comment: In Haskell types don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, as I haven't done much Haskell, but it's a possibility: You can define a `trait` that can only be mixed into specific instances of a tree:

```
trait StringFooFunctionality {
   this: Tree[String] => // Selftype, can only be mixed in to classes that are Tree[String]
   def foo = "Yay" // String is the datatype of Tree here
}
```

You would use this like this:

```
val sNode = new Node(Leaf("a"), Leaf("b")) with StringFooFunctionality
sNode.foo
// Yay
```

The downside is that it explicitly needs to be mixed in on object creation.

Other possibility is to create a new trait called `StringTree`:

```
trait StringTree extends Tree[String] {
   def foo = ...
}
```

But you would have to define the other `String` datatypes:

```
case class StringLeaf(t: String) extends StringTree
case class StringNode(left: StringTree, right: StringTree) extends StringTree
```

And when you encounter a `Tree[T]` you can pattern match on it to see if it's `StringTree`.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell types don't have instance methods like Scala does.

`foo` in your example should be defined (preferably) in `Tree`'s companion object.

```
sealed abstract class Tree[T]()
case class Leaf[T](t: T) extends Tree[T]
case class Node[T](left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]

object Tree {
  // Method only for Tree[String]:
  def foo(tree: Tree[String]) = ...
}
```

---

PS: IMO a `sealed` class or trait is more appropriate here. ([Scala's sealed abstract vs abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032771/scalas-sealed-abstract-vs-abstract-class))

PS II: I am just typing Gregor Raýman's comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way (and equivalent to Haskell) is to define a method which takes `Tree[String]` as an argument, as in muhuk's answer. If you want it to look like a method on `Tree[String]`, you can use implicit class:

```
implicit class Foo(val tree: Tree[String]) {
  def foo = ...
}

val tree: Tree[String] = ...

tree.foo // Foo needs to be in scope here
```

I recommend avoiding Akos Krivachy's answer in most circumstances.